# How do I get the string value from a pointer-reference using FFI::Platypus?

Tags: ffi, perl

I've built a shared library in C with,

```
const char foo[] = "foo1234";
```

With [FFI::Platypus](https://metacpan.org/pod/FFI::Platypus) I can get the symbol location using

```
print $ffi->find_symbol('foo');
140204212527104
```

How do I print out the value of `foo1234`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the `SVpv` you need to cast the "opaque" pointer to a Perl data variable,

```
$ffi->cast(opaque => string => $ffi->find_symbol('foo'));
```

You can [see this here in the test suite.](https://metacpan.org/source/PLICEASE/FFI-Platypus-0.87/t/ffi_platypus.t#L574)

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you know the location and length of the buffer is `buffer_to_scalar` from [FFI::Platypus::Buffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/FFI::Platypus::Buffer). This is a very close to metal and thus quick option, but it is dangerous like most C code is, you can easily segfault by using it wrong.